# Convert TFont.Pitch into an Integer value?

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-10.3-rio

I use this method to convert `TFont.Pitch` into an `Integer` value:

```
var
  ThisPitch: Integer;

case Font.Pitch of
    TFontPitch.fpDefault:  ThisPitch := 0;
    TFontPitch.fpVariable: ThisPitch := 1;
    TFontPitch.fpFixed:    ThisPitch := 2;
end;
```

Is there a simpler method to convert `TFont.Pitch` into an `Integer` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TFontPitch` enum values have the same numeric values that you are converting to, so a simple `Ord()` conversion will suffice:

```pascal
var
  ThisPitch: Integer;

ThisPitch := Ord(Font.Pitch);
```